# Composition $F\circ g$ of Sobolev function $g \in W^{k,2}(\mathbb R^n)$ with smooth map $F$ is Sobolev

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Let $F: \R\to \mathbb R$  be a *smooth* function such that $F(0) = 0$.
Now consider $g\in W^{k,2}(\R^n)$ (Sobolev space) with $k>n/2$.

> Is it true that $F\circ g\in W^{k,2}(\R^n) $?

**My attempt:**

1. $F\circ g \in L^2$ because by Sobolev embedding theorem $g$ is Holder (hence uniformely continuous) and in $L^2$, thus $g(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to +\infty$ and $F$ satisfies
   $F(g(t)) \leq 0 + \sup_{|s|<\epsilon}\{\partial F(s)\} \cdot (g(t)) \leq const. g(t)$ for $t$ large enough (so that $|g(t)|<\epsilon$).
2. Since $F$ is smooth, then  $F\circ g \in W^{k,2}_{loc}(\R^n)$  (*locally* Sobolev) with weak derivatives given by iterative applications of  the chain rule, for example $\partial_x (F\circ g)(x) = \partial F(g(x))\partial_x g(x)$ (this should follow by a density argument+ locally Lipshitzianity of $F$).
3. It remains to verify that the weak derivatives lie in $L^2$. In the case of the first derivative, $\partial F(g(x))$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $\infty$ and $\partial_x g(x)\in L^2$, therefore their product is in $L^2$. For higher derivatives, it is more complicated but seems to be true looking for example at the case of $\R^1$ where the second derivative is $\partial^2 F (\partial g)^2 + \partial F \partial^2 g $ which is in $W^{k,2}(\R)$ because  $\partial^2 F$ and $\partial F$ are bounded in a neighbourhood of $\infty$, and multiplication $W^{1,2}(\R)\times W^{1,2}(\R)\to W^{1,2}(\R)$ is continuous. Is there a trick for the general case maybe?
4. What about fractional derivatives?

Comment: yes, but I don't have an easy proof for you. You may consider Theorem 2.61 of Bahouri--Chemin--Danchin's book "Fourier analysis and nonlinear partial diﬀerential equations"  doi: 10.1007/978-3-642- 16830-7. The proof goes through Besov spaces

Comment: @CalvinKhor thank you for the reference and the checking! 
If I may ask, do you think the proof should go through without any problems in the case when $g$ takes values in $X$ (say a Banach) and $F:X\to Y$ (smooth $F(0)=0$)  with $Y$ Banach?

Comment: You're welcome; I would assume yes...